# Unrecognized Font Family on React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, fonts, react-native

I'm running into a peculiar error using React Native. Inside my `button.js` I am doing

```
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
const icon = (Icon name="menu size={20} color="green"/>);
render()
    return(
         {icon}
    )
```

But I'm given the error

```
Unrecognized Font Family 'Material Icons'
```

However when I import FontAwesome as:

```
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
```

I get no error.

Comment: Simply restarting the project does seem to solve the problem.

Comment: just reset the project using npm start -- --reset cache command in the terminal, then make the bundle file index.android.bundle,
After that -> react-native run-android

Answer (score 28):

The same issue was fixed after triggering `loadFont()` method

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

Icon.loadFont();
```

Comment: trigger this method where?

Comment: After the import statement as per answer

Comment: This was super helpful to me. Thank you. I did not want to go down another rabbit hole of messing with my pod files since I already spent hours fixing issues there.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you have run the command:

> react-native link react-native-vector-icons

Comment: Don't forget to recompile your project using `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android`.

Comment: **Important:** For RN 0.60 and above we dont need to manually link libs, even if we link it manually we have to unlink it otherwise error will be thrown.

Answer (score 7):

```
npm install --save react-native-vector-icons
```

add the line below to the ios/podfile file then run `pod update`

```
pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

in the ios/projectNameFolder/info.plist add codes below between  tags. If you already have this UIAppFonts array just edit strings. Be sure you have fonts under node_modules>react-native-vector-icons

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
  <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
  <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
  <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Feather.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
  <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
  <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
  <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
  <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
  <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```

clean cache and restart application with rebuild. It suppose to work.

Answer (score 3):

The library you use has a specific [section about this problem](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#red-screen-with-unrecognized-font-family-error-on-ios), it states (in version 2.0.3):

- Make sure you've added the fonts to your XCode project.
- Check that the font you are trying to use appears in Info.plist, if you've added the whole folder and it's blue in color, then you need to add it to the path.
- Check that the font is copied in the Copy Bundle Resources
  in Build Phases.
- Recompile the project.

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned I'd done all that. It was specifically an issue with Material Icons. I solved it by simply restarting the project and copying over all the files to a new directory. Not sure if that's an acceptable solution so I didn't post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you have completed all the above steps and still get the same error, you need to **Clean** your iOS project from Xcode then **Build** it. This will completely reset the project and ensure that the .ttf file is included.

Run your project from within Xcode and it should now work.

You may still find your project still doesn't work using `react-native run-ios`. If this is the case, open Finder and navigate to the **ios** folder in your project and delete the entire **build** folder. Then close your simulator and package manager terminal, and run `react-native run-ios` again. This will take a couple of minutes as it's rebuilding everything, but then (hopefully) your app will run correctly.

[image: Clean and Build in Xcode]

[image: Delete the ios/build folder]

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf node_modules, npm install

cd android
gradlew clean

cd ..

npm install --save react-native-vector-icons
react-native link
```

run and confirm it's working

Answer (score -1):

- Make sure that you already imported .ttf files to your project.
- check in the copy bundle Resources as well.
- Finally, add the files in info.plist as in the image [Image Link](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/378279/12421498/2db1f93a-be88-11e5-89c8-2e563ba6251a.png)